# проблема добавить bindingsource на datagridview

Tags: c#

У меня контролл **bindingSource1** в конструкторе формы добавляется только на **Form1**, а на **dataGridView1** не добавляется. И поэтому - не могу выбрать "Источник данных" в **dataGridView1** как **bindingSource1**. Подскажите пожалуйста как решить

Я ожидал что контролл **bindingSource1** в конструкторе формы добавиться без проблем на **dataGridView1** как видно на некоторых роликах

Я так тоже попробовал. Сначала кинул **bindingsource**, а потом кинул **datagridview**. Но в **datagridview** в раскрывающемся списке "Выбрать источник данных" есть только один пункт: "**Нет**"

```
namespace WinFormsApp1
{
  partial class Form1
  {
    /// <summary>
    ///  Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    ///  Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
      if (disposing && (components != null))
      {
        components.Dispose();
      }
      base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    ///  Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    ///  the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
      components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
      tableLayoutPanel1 = new TableLayoutPanel();
      dataGridView1 = new DataGridView();
      btnRefresh = new Button();
      bindingSource1 = new BindingSource(components);
      tableLayoutPanel1.SuspendLayout();
      ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)dataGridView1).BeginInit();
      ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)bindingSource1).BeginInit();
      SuspendLayout();
      // 
      // tableLayoutPanel1
      // 
      tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount = 2;
      tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 50F));
      tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 50F));
      tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(dataGridView1, 0, 0);
      tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(btnRefresh, 1, 1);
      tableLayoutPanel1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
      tableLayoutPanel1.Location = new Point(0, 0);
      tableLayoutPanel1.Name = "tableLayoutPanel1";
      tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = 2;
      tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 100F));
      tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle());
      tableLayoutPanel1.Size = new Size(773, 450);
      tableLayoutPanel1.TabIndex = 0;
      // 
      // dataGridView1
      // 
      dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
      dataGridView1.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
      dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
      tableLayoutPanel1.SetColumnSpan(dataGridView1, 2);
      dataGridView1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
      dataGridView1.Location = new Point(3, 3);
      dataGridView1.Name = "dataGridView1";
      dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
      dataGridView1.RowTemplate.Height = 25;
      dataGridView1.Size = new Size(767, 415);
      dataGridView1.TabIndex = 1;
      // 
      // btnRefresh
      // 
      btnRefresh.Location = new Point(389, 424);
      btnRefresh.Name = "btnRefresh";
      btnRefresh.Size = new Size(75, 23);
      btnRefresh.TabIndex = 0;
      btnRefresh.Text = "Refresh";
      btnRefresh.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
      btnRefresh.Click += btnRefresh_Click;
      // 
      // Form1
      // 
      AutoScaleDimensions = new SizeF(7F, 15F);
      AutoScaleMode = AutoScaleMode.Font;
      ClientSize = new Size(773, 450);
      Controls.Add(tableLayoutPanel1);
      Name = "Form1";
      Text = "Form1";
      tableLayoutPanel1.ResumeLayout(false);
      ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)dataGridView1).EndInit();
      ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)bindingSource1).EndInit();
      ResumeLayout(false);
    }

    #endregion

    private TableLayoutPanel tableLayoutPanel1;
    private Button btnRefresh;
    private DataGridView dataGridView1;
    private BindingSource bindingSource1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Покажите код. Что мешает просто написать `dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1;`?

Comment: А кода нет. Потому что я пытаюсь это делать в Конструкторе формы. Обновил Студию и попробовал вот так: Сначала кинул bindingsource, а потом кинул datagridview. Но в datagridview в раскрывающемся списке "Выбрать источник данных" есть только один пункт: "Нет"

Comment: Отредактируйте вопрос, вставьте код туда.

Comment: спасибо большое - так как вы сказали написать код получилось. Просто интересно - почему это не получилось сделать в окне Конструктора формы ?